# dynamic search folder in Outlook professional 2010

Tags: search, outlook, instant

I want to create a search folder that will prompt/take user input (I will enter it manually)
and search all the emails containing that String.

Basically what I am trying to enter is something dynamic and hence I want to pass that string dynamically to the search criteria. is it possible.

Cause: I try to search using the instant search but it finds all emails not with the exact sentence but with all the words in the sentence i typed.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Searching for a sentence with in quotes in the instant search area.... i.e.

"your sentence goes here"

will automatically search the complete sentence...

Here is a nice link for that.. really helpful

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-HA010238831.aspx